# Element showing as null on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, smooch

I am trying to attach a hover function to a dynamic div ID that is being generated by a script (using Smooch api). The function doesn't work even when I run it in my console after everything has been loaded.

I tried doing:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#messenger-button", function() {
    alert("hey")
});
```

and I keep getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

The html that is being generated after the Smooch api is initiated looks like this:

```
<iframe>
 <html>
   <div id="messenger-button" style="background-color: rgb(10, 74, 119);>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

There is no function that is allowing me to add a class, change the css, or do anything to change the properties for the div in the generated iframe. Can anyone who has used Smooch api tell me how I can add a hover state to the messenger button that is generated?

Comment: Well sounds like you do not have jQuery. The $ in the console is not jQuery... $ is querySelector in chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Unless the iframe is from the same domain as your site, you cannot access the contents of the iframe that way.

Comment: @epascarello I do have jQuery installed. I am able to user jQuery to attach a hover state to static divs I created. It just doesn't work for the dynamic content.

Comment: jQuery would not return undefined

Comment: @epascarello well it is. If I run `$("#messenger-button")` in my console I get this `<div id="messenger-button`></div>`

But if I run `$("#messenger-button").addClass("new-messenger");` I get this `TypeError: $(...).addClass is not a function`

Comment: Which is NOT a jQuery object.  The `$` is a short cut for `document.querySelector` like I mentioned an hour ago. And `$$()` is `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference

Comment: @epascarello sorry, but I do have jQuery installed and I am using it...how do you suggest I test if I am running it or now?

Comment: run `console.log($);` in the console and post what it returns. Than do `console.log(jQuery);`

Comment: @epascarello I get this `ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}`

Comment: @NehaSohail given jquery is working is my answer not working for you ?

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to select the iframe and get its contents and change the elements from there, see.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var iFrameDOM = $("iframe").contents();

    iFrameDOM.find("#messenger-button").addClass("new-messenger");
});
```